# Avoid session sharing JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session

I am setting session like this on my `servlet.java`side,

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("File_Text", fileTxt);
```

and on my jsp page I access this by using,

```
<div id="editor">${File_Text}</div>
```

Now, when I open `my.jsp` page on another tab, this session value is populated into the div tag

How do I avoid session sharing in my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First learn about sessions.

Sessions start when your website is opened in a particular browser and is carried on with different tabs in the **same** browser.

A new session will be created only if it expires after certain tiemout or if the browser is closed.

Sessions are specific to browser and not tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Dear session is meant for getting values across the users interaction with application eg(servlets,jsp). There is nothing like session sharing in your case,So in your case you may use Page or Request scope attributes to prevent access in other pages. Hope this helps

Comment: I am getting the same session value into my new tab also?

Comment: Till session time out you have same values, despite of tabs

Answer (score 0):

It is the same session so you will get the data, if you want that object just to live for request then set it in `request`

Comment: setting it in request??

Comment: `request.setAttribute("File_Text", fileTxt);`

Comment: I've done that but the same text is being populated onto my new tab also :?

Comment: well it lives for a life of request if you attempt to set same object then you will get same object in diffferent request